# I have forgotten / I forgot something

Tags: present-perfect-vs-simple-past

If I say, for example :

> I have forgotten (*or* I forgot) my phone at your place. Can you bring it to me tomorrow ?

Which one is correct? What is the best way to say it?

For me it's "I have forgotten" because there is a consequence in the present, but I'm not sure .... :( It's why I am asking you guys :)

Comment: I would say "I left/have left my phone there". Either tense would do, but I would use _have left_ immediately after finding the phone missing.

Comment: Thank you very much :)